# How to call a method into a ticker Button as command

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

In the tkinter GUI I created a run Button. I liked to click the button then it should start counting. But When I call the method into the ttk.Button as command. it does not work. In this code two class was created. run method was created in the first class and it will be call into the second class. Could you please kindly check the code. Thanks in advance.

```
    from tkinter import *
    import threading
    import queue
    from time import sleep
    import random
    from tkinter import ttk

    class Thread_0(threading.Thread):

        def __init__(self):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        def run(self):
            count = 0
            while True:
                count +=1
                hmi.thread_0_update(count)
                sleep(random.random()/100)


     class HMI:
        def __init__(self):
            self.master=Tk()
            self.master.geometry('200x200+1+1')

            self.f=ttk.Frame(self.master,height = 100, width = 100, relief= 'ridge')

            self.f.grid(row=1,column=1, padx=20, pady=20)

            self.l0=ttk.Label(self.f)
            self.l0.grid(row=1,column=1)

            self.button=ttk.Button(self.master, text = 'run')
            self.button.grid(row=2,column=2)

            self.q0=queue.Queue()

            self.master.bind("<<Thread_0_Label_Update>>",self.thread_0_update_e)

        def start(self):
            self.master.mainloop()
            self.master.destroy()

    #################################
        def thread_0_update(self,val):
            self.q0.put(val)

            self.master.event_generate('<<Thread_0_Label_Update>>',when='tail')
        def thread_0_update_e(self,e):
            while self.q0.qsize():
                try:
                   val=self.q0.get()
                   self.l0.config(text=str(val), font = ('Times New Roman', 15))
                except queue.Empty:
                    pass


##########################
    if __name__=='__main__':
        hmi=HMI()
        t0=Thread_0()
        t0.start()
        hmi.start()
```

Comment: do you get error message ? Always put full `Traceback` in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
 Button( ..., command=t0.start )
```

See: `start` is without `()`. But you have to create `t0` before `hmi`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t0 = Thread_0()
    hmi = HMI()
    hmi.start()
```

Full code which works for me

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
import queue
from time import sleep
import random
from tkinter import ttk

class Thread_0(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        count = 0
        while True:
            count +=1
            hmi.thread_0_update(count)
            sleep(random.random()/100)


class HMI:

    def __init__(self):
        self.master=Tk()
        self.master.geometry('200x200+1+1')

        self.f = ttk.Frame(self.master, height=100, width=100, relief='ridge')

        self.f.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.l0 = ttk.Label(self.f)
        self.l0.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.button = ttk.Button(self.master, text='run', command=t0.start)
        self.button.grid(row=2, column=2)

        self.q0 = queue.Queue()

        self.master.bind("<<Thread_0_Label_Update>>", self.thread_0_update_e)

    def start(self):
        self.master.mainloop()
        self.master.destroy()

#################################
    def thread_0_update(self,val):
        self.q0.put(val)

        self.master.event_generate('<<Thread_0_Label_Update>>', when='tail')
    def thread_0_update_e(self,e):
        while self.q0.qsize():
            try:
               val = self.q0.get()
               self.l0.config(text=str(val), font=('Times New Roman', 15))
            except queue.Empty:
                pass


##########################
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t0 = Thread_0()
    hmi = HMI()
    hmi.start()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working perfectly. One question, is it possible to put the number one after one, rather than replacing. What I mean I want to have all the number on the Frame or Text or master.

Comment: you can get all text from label, concatenate new text and put it back - `self.l0.config(text=self.l0.cget("text") + str(val))` or `self.l0["text"] = self.l0["text"] + str(val)`. With `Text()` you can insert new text at the end `text.insert("end", str(val))`. You can also add new `Label` with text after old one - this way you will have many labels in window but every label may have different background color.